# If docker container ip and external network ip is same, then which one will get respond if will do telnet? any idea

Tags: docker

If docker container IP and external network IP is the same, then which one will get respond if it will do telnet?

I know below configuration is the worst configuration, but I want to know the behaviour.

Give you one example

My application is running in localhost which is talking to the database inside the docker container.
Custom IP we provided - (IP : 10.0.0.1, PORT :5432)

Another database running outside the container, let say both container (IP and port) and host (IP and port) are the same.
HOST IP : 10.0.0.1, HOST PORT :5432

Which one will connect by application host/container-database or both the database?

or

If will do the telnet 10.0.0.1 5432? which one will respond and why?

[Explain in Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXZpq.jpg)

Comment: If you expose port to host machine and on host machine some process on the exact same port is alredy running, then your container will not be able to bind port. Basically, this eould be the same if you jave two databases on host machine both on same port. If you will do telnet, the first one that started running will give you response (because only one db will be running)

Comment: In other words, your machine can see two different peers with the same IP address? That means your network configuration is hosed and you'll have a lot of dropped packets and/or misroutes.

Comment: By using external network ip (public ip) connect to server 2 database and my docker container is running in Server 1 and application is on Host server not in container.

Comment: Thanks @deceze. I know that packet lose will happen, But which is the first priority?

Comment: @deceze your answer is useful, Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's possible, even if you have the same IP (somehow) for the container and the host, you won't be able to map the container port 5432 to the host port 5432, because there's already an application (host dB) running on that port.

Consider a scenario where you are using the host network for the container as well, probably by using the `--network host`. This way your container IP will be the same as the host IP. The container will be using the 5432 port of the host to run the dB. Now, if you try to start the dB on the host using the same port, you should get an error that port is already being used.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comment. Can you please go through the attached diagram for better understanding..

Comment: In the diagram, what do you mean by host1 and host2? I have updated my answer for better understanding.

Comment: Sorry my bad. Host means server 1 and server 2.

Comment: By using external network ip (public ip) connect to server 2 database and my docker container is running in Server 1 and application is on Host server not in container.

Comment: So, are you trying to say that you have 2 servers, the application is running on server1 and db is running on a container inside server1 and on server2. Is that right? But if that's the scenario, how can server1  and server2 have the same ip?

Comment: We can set the static IP to the container which is private sub-net on the server 1 and server 2 have the same ip as container ip.